# Resources for learning business Japanese

Tags: business-japanese

So,

I just landed my dream job working for a consulting firm in Tokyo. I am currently N1 (and above), but I lack a lot of business keigo expressions (FOR EXAMPLE) (ご都合時間であれば教えていただけろと幸いです」「是非とも評価させていただければと思います」 and industry terminology.

How do you proceed from this level (fully fluent, not learning anything new from JSL books) to being able to do business in Japanese (conducting meetings, negotiating contracts, etc)?

There is no information on how to overcome this gap in lack of vocabulary and naturalized keigo expressions.

It seems that most resources available are either really low level for foreigners, and stylistic "communication" books for native Japanese speakers.

Comment: No resources exist yet on this topic.
This should be a special case as it facilitates learning without betraying the fact you want people checking for preexisting resources before spamming the board.

But here is a stupid reword to satisfy the arbitrary requirement.

"What are Keigo expressions and vocabulary used in Japanese business mails, meetings, and projects that may prove useful to someone working purely in Japanese with C-level executives and engineers."

And no I don't need basic Keigo grammar or instructions on how to write a simple email/report update in Keigo.

Comment: I tried to re-open and close this so it could be migrated to meta, but the post was too old to be migrated, so I ended up closing it again.

Answer (score 3):

If your level is N1 and above, how about reading resources for university students who are hunting job (就活)? Since those resources target beginner in business, I think they are the best resources you can get online.
For example, [this site](http://freshers.adecco.co.jp/knowhow/manner/wording.html) tells basic honorific expression (敬語). And [this site](http://www.elite-network.co.jp/x/dictionary/consulcontent.html) has list for terminology (業界用語) used in consulting firm.

 
If you can visit bookstore, there are also books for job hunting students.

Comment: Yes these are both great suggestions for beginners, but I need more advanced Japanese keigo. I need to be able to speak with engineers and negotiate contracts.

I was hoping for a more foreigner geared English ==> Japanese

Maybe I'll need to do some Japanese ==> English guides.

Comment: Now I understand your situation properly. Let me check if there is any resources.

Comment: Some of the tech terms are useful, but a lot are very basic 外来語

I'm talking about terms like 
歪補正　
交代行列
etc.

As of right now I'm using Japanese business dictionaries to find a semi-native English translation, but that's a slow way to study.